VBA - change cell formatting based on another cell's format
How to change cell formatting based on another cell's format?
I tried the following code:
Range("A9:A9").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=LEN(A9)>40"

Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

If Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 255 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Interior.Color = 255
End If

Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = 0 Then ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Interior.Color = 255

Thanks for reply , but seen not working yet,  highlight to A8 without in range highlight.

Range("A9:A9").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=LEN(A9)>40"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
    
End With

If Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 255 Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Interior.Color = 255
End If
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

I think you should edit your question and carefully explain what you are asking for.

Pls explain on the specific issues you encountered. And what's your expected result?

in my code first part is start from A9 to last row as len more than 40 will color 255.

Please edit your post to share the code. The code in comment loses line break.

and to 2nd part if range A9 to last have color 255, then A8 will color 255 else no color

Any helps? now code is Highlight to A8 without check condition
